# How to move a file in to zip compressed format

Tags: php, file, upload

i am using move_upload_file function to move the file to my folder,its work fine but i want compressed zip format.plz any body help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/book.zip.php

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Zip extension:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/zip.examples.php

I looked at the code you linked to (it would have been good if you included it in the question) and made a few changes:

```
$nameFile = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$download_folder = './files/';

$zip = new ZipArchive();
$fileconpress = $download_folder.$nameFile.".zip";

$conpress = $zip->open($fileconpress, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE);
if ($conpress === true)
{
    $zip->addFile($tmpName);
    $zip->close();
    echo $fileconpress."<br/>";
    echo "yess !! Success!!!! ";
}
else echo " Oh No! Error";
```

The important part and likely what's causing your error is $download_folder. You need to define the path of where you want to save the file.

I also removed the `fread()`, you can just load the file straight into the zip object with `addFile()`